# XML DOM SelectSingleNode() with namespace not returning the node

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

I have hit a problem with selecting nodes with namespaces in MSXML. The XML has been generated by the ADODB recordset and looks like this:

```
<xml>
    <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema" >
        <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly" rs:updatable="true" >
            <s:AttributeType name="ID" rs:number="1" rs:basecatalog="SystemDB" rs:basetable="pagehits" rs:basecolumn="ID" rs:keycolumn="true" rs:autoincrement="true" >
                <s:datatype dt:type="int" dt:maxLength="4" rs:precision="10" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:maybenull="false" />
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="SessionCode" rs:number="2" rs:writeunknown="true" rs:basecatalog="SystemDB" rs:basetable="pagehits" rs:basecolumn="SessionCode" >
                <s:datatype dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str" dt:maxLength="36" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:maybenull="false" />
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="PagePath" rs:number="3" rs:writeunknown="true" rs:basecatalog="SystemDB" rs:basetable="pagehits" rs:basecolumn="PagePath" >
                <s:datatype dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str" dt:maxLength="100" rs:maybenull="false" />
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="PersID" rs:number="4" rs:writeunknown="true" rs:basecatalog="SystemDB" rs:basetable="pagehits" rs:basecolumn="PersID" >
                <s:datatype dt:type="int" dt:maxLength="4" rs:precision="10" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:maybenull="false" />
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="PersonInfo" rs:number="5" rs:writeunknown="true" rs:basecatalog="SystemDB" rs:basetable="pagehits" rs:basecolumn="PersonInfo" >
                <s:datatype dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str" dt:maxLength="100" rs:maybenull="false" />
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="CRD" rs:number="6" rs:writeunknown="true" rs:basecatalog="SystemDB" rs:basetable="pagehits" rs:basecolumn="CRD" >
                <s:datatype dt:type="dateTime" rs:dbtype="timestamp" dt:maxLength="16" rs:scale="3" rs:precision="23" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:maybenull="false" />
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:extends type="rs:rowbase" />
        </s:ElementType>
    </s:Schema>
    <rs:data>
        <z:row ID="1" SessionCode="2CA43F6A-3951-42C5-8FF4-C6409026ED3A" PagePath="/pages/home/home.asp" PersID="2" PersonInfo="User395959" CRD="2014-04-07T23:30:38.090000000" />
        <z:row ID="2" SessionCode="2CA43F6A-3951-42C5-8FF4-C6409026ED3A" PagePath="/pages/home/home.asp" PersID="2" PersonInfo="User395959" CRD="2014-04-07T23:30:51.180000000" />
        <z:row ID="3" SessionCode="2CA43F6A-3951-42C5-8FF4-C6409026ED3A" PagePath="/pages/home/home_v02.asp" PersID="2" PersonInfo="User395959" CRD="2014-04-07T23:30:51.240000000" />
        <z:row ID="4" SessionCode="2CA43F6A-3951-42C5-8FF4-C6409026ED3A" PagePath="/pages/home/home.asp" PersID="2" PersonInfo="User395959" CRD="2014-04-07T23:30:54.180000000" />
        <z:row ID="5" SessionCode="2CA43F6A-3951-42C5-8FF4-C6409026ED3A" PagePath="/pages/home/home_v02.asp" PersID="2" PersonInfo="User395959" CRD="2014-04-07T23:30:54.213000000" />
    </rs:data>
</xml>
```

I have loaded the XML string into an XML document named **oXMLDoc**. I now want to select the s:Schema node, so I have used this code to select the node and report the type of the selected node object:

```
oXMLDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", " xmlns:s='http://dev.kauupm.com/ns_s' "
dim oSchemaNode: set oSchemaNode = oXMLDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//s:Schema")
oTracer.Trace "", "Schema node is type: " & typeName(oSchemaNode)
```

The result reported by the tracer is that the type is Nothing, so the node was not found.

I have tried a number of different combinations of xpath to no avail. However, if I strip out all the namespaces from the XML text before loading it into the XML object, then select the Schema node without the namespace, it works fine! So, the problem lies somewhere in the namespace, but I can't see what I am doing wrong and I am very puzzled.

I am using Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0.

Any help much appreciated - John

Comment: The XML you posted does not declare any namespace (it doesn't have an xmlns='http://dev.kauupm.com/ns_s' attribute. Actually it should declare all the prefixes you need.

Comment: @helderdarocha Thank you for your comment - I think this has led me to the answer to the problem - I will post again shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this problem lay in not understanding that namespaces represented by prefixes must match. The source xml generated by the ADODB recordset has its own namespaces declared as follows:

```
xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset' 
xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema' 
xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
```

I was using a different namespace in my setProperty parameters. So although I was using the s: prefix in the path for the selectSingleNode call, the corresponding namespace did not match the namespace of the s: prefix in the XML.

So I changed the setProperty to

```
'// Set the namespaces used for selection - they must match the namespaces from Microsoft
oXMLDoc.setProperty  "SelectionNamespaces", "  xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' " _
                                    & " xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset' " _
                                    & " xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema' " _
                                    & " xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882' "   _
                                    & " xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882' "
```

and now it works perfectly.

I had not appreciated that the prefix is just a symbol representing a namespace, and it is the namespaces that must match, not just the prefixes.

Many thanks to @helderdarocha.

John